# Laravel New project [Error]

Tags: php, html, laravel, terminal

just installed laravel on my machine, but when I type

```
laravel new project
```

It tells me that the command does not exist :/

Error :

```
 zsh: command not found: laravel
```

Comment: Did you do `composer global require "laravel/installer"` first ?

Comment: But, wait, you said you installed laravel, then why would you do `laravel new project` ?

Comment: Try the guide on the site - https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick

Comment: Make sure composer is set right in your path variable.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have done so far, from the beginning? I don't think anyone who has answered so far is completely clear on the steps you completed prior to typing `laravel new project`

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the following to your `.zshrc` file?

```
# User configuration
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: You'll need to log off and log on again after adding the path, or type `source .zshrc` to refresh it.